# Jenkins SubWCRev E155036 working copy is too old

Tags: svn, jenkins

im getting an error during the build process on our Jenkins Server, since i tried to use the Tortoise SubWCRev.exe in a prebuild Event to get the Revision number and place it in the assembly file.

This is the Error:

> PreBuildEvent:
>     SubWCRev.exe "...\Jenkins\jobs... " "...\Jenkins\jobs...\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.template " "...\Jenkins\jobs...\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "
>
> SubWCRev : E155036: The working copy at '...\Jenkins\jobs...\workspace\code'
>     is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.10 (r1615264)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

When i do a Rebuild on my local machine it works fine and replaces the Revisionumber in the AssemblyInfo.cs File.

I am pretty new to Subversioning and Jenkins, so i dont have a clue at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution was quite simply in the end...

You have to update the Jenkins Subversion Plug-In to Version 2.5 or higher (I've done it to 2.5.2). After you update the Plug-In you have to set Subversion to Version 1.8 (this is done in Jenkins / system configuration / Subversion )

Comment: Also clean the workspace of the project with the working copy in the old schema version.

Comment: For my case, I had to set the subversion version to 1.8 as above, but I also had to right click on the workspace and click SVN update workspace to vNNN. Deleting the workspace as Mike D suggests would probably work as well.